# Storing a common value for the 'employee code' while employing inheritance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, inheritance

There are 3 `pojo` namely `EmployeeMaster` *(the parent class)*, `Hr` and `Personal` *(the child class of EmployeeMaster)*.

Then I have 3 separate tables for each `pojo`, constructed as :

```
create table emp_master(emp_code integer,emp_name text,emp_desig text,
emp_dept text,primary key(emp_code));

create table hr(emp_code integer,salary integer,hra integer,da integer,
taxes integer,grade text,foreign key(emp_code) references emp_master(emp_code));

create table personal(emp_code integer,address text,married bool,
foreign key(emp_code) references emp_master(emp_code));
```

`emp_code` is the primary key for `emp_master` and it is the foreign key for both `hr` and `personal` table.

I constructed 3 separate `jsp` forms to take in the data.

Following is the `hibernate mapping` file :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="pojo.EmployeeMaster" table="emp_master">
      <id name="emp_code">
          <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>
      <property name="emp_dept" />
      <property name="emp_desig" />
      <property name="emp_name" />

      <joined-subclass name="pojo.Hr" table="hr">
          <key column="emp_code" />
          <property name="da" />
          <property name="grade" />
          <property name="hra" />
          <property name="salary" />
          <property name="taxes" />
      </joined-subclass>

      <joined-subclass name="pojo.Personal" table="personal">
          <key column="emp_code" />
          <property name="address" />
          <property name="married" />
      </joined-subclass>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now the problem is,I do not want any `null` row and want to submit data for the same `emp_code` into other tables namely `hr` and `personal`.

But as I try to submit data into the `hr` table for `emp_code 101`, that already exists in the `master table` I get an error saying `Duplicate entry '101' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

If I change the `generator class to increment` in the mapping xml, I get a row with null values,for the data inserted from the child class.What I want is an entry into the three tables with the same `employee code`. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hibernate mapping suggests that you `EmployeeMaster`, `HR` and `personal` forms a hierarchy, i.e. `EmployeeMaster` is parent class, while `HR` and `Personal` are child classes.

There is something wrong in what you want to achieve and what your mapping suggesting. In above mapping, an `ID` can be mapped to either `HR` or to `Personal` and not both.

You should consider changing the mapping from **INHERITANCE** to **ASSOCIATION**.

As per your mapping xml, your java classes should be defined as follows:

```
public class EmployeeMaster {}

public class HR extends EmployeeMaster{}

public class Personal extends EmployeeMaster{}
```

Now, you have to device how you can fit your requirements into above model. If that is not the case, then you have no choice but to change the model (xml mapping as well)

Comment: I can only use inheritance. I can change the mapping xml though

Comment: that is what i asked. **How do i do this ?** java classes are defined as you suggested

Comment: that is conceptually wrong. You can't do that. Think about it, a HR and a Personal, both are EmployeeMaster. And there can be only one EmployeeMaster with one emp_code.

Comment: yeah..but HR is EmployeeMaster. Thus HR can have the same code as emp_master

Comment: Yes, ideally there will be no stand-alone EmployeeMaster. Here is what happens:  When you try to save a HR or Personal object, hibernate will insert a corresponding entry into EmployeeMaster first. So, you are getting error because you already have an EmployeeMaster with the same ID. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: give a solution..I know the reason for the problem..I cannot use association but inheritance..or is there ain't a solution ?

Comment: Remove inheritance mapping from mapping file. Then it should work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31561/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-vineet)